A curious norm related to the L¹ norm
If $f \in C^0([0,1])$, one can define
$$\Vert f \Vert_? = \sup_{J \subset [0,1]} \left\lvert \int_J f \right\rvert,$$
where $J$ runs among all subintervals of $[0,1]$.
This is a norm on $C^0([0,1])$ (and Lebesgue's density theorem shows that this generalizes on spaces like $L^1(I)$, where $I$ is an interval, but I don't really want to go to this generality).
The norm is strictly coarser than the $L^1$ norm, but it satisfies something reminiscent of it: if $f, g \in C^0([0,1])$ are such that $f$ is monotonic, then one gets
$$ \left\vert \int_0^1 f g \right\rvert \leq C \Vert f \Vert_\infty \Vert g \Vert_?,$$
for some universal constant $C$. If I'm not mistaken, $C = 2$ works, thanks to the second mean value theorem for integrals.
This norm and this inequality appear in the background of the classical Jordan's theorem saying that the Fourier series of a BV function converges: the point is that whereas the L¹ norm of the Dirichlet kernel goes to infinity, such isn't the case with this norm.
If you had the patience to read all of this, my questions are the following:

is this norm (or a variant of it) well-known? has it got a name?
do you know what is the best constant $C$?


I asked the question on MSE, but go no real answer, despite a bounty → https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4976792/a-curious-norm-related-to-the-l%c2%b9-norm

Your norm satisfies $|F'|? = \sup F - \inf F$ and it is comparable to the supremum norm of the antiderivative: $\sup |F| \leqslant |F'|? \leqslant 2 \sup |F|$ if $F(x) = 0$ for some $x \in [0, 1]$. In particular, if, given $f$, we choose $F = \int f$ in such a way that $\sup F = -\inf F$, then $|f|? =2 \sup |F| = 2 |F|\infty$. So your norm seems to be related (or maybe simply equal) to the norm of $W^{-1,\infty}([0,1])$.

I think $C=2$ is the best constant. Consider $\varepsilon>0$ and let $f,g$ continuous in $[0,1]$ defined as follows.
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \begin{cases} -1, & 0\leq x \leq \frac12 - \varepsilon \\
1, & \frac12 + \varepsilon \leq x \leq 1, \\
\text{linear}, & |x-\frac12| \leq \varepsilon
\end{cases},
\end{equation*}
and $g\in C^0[0,1]$ such that $\Vert g - (-\chi_{(1/4,1/2)}+\chi_{(1/2,1/4)})\Vert_{L^1[0,1]} < \varepsilon. $
Then
$$ \Big| \int_0^1 f g \, dx \Big | = \frac12 + O(\varepsilon) $$ and
$$ \Vert g \Vert_? \leq \Vert g- (-\chi_{(1/4,1/2)}+\chi_{(1/2,1/4)})\Vert_{L^1[0,1]} + \Vert -\chi_{(1/4,1/2)}+\chi_{(1/2,1/4)} \Vert_? = \frac14 + O(\varepsilon)  $$
